# Running kubectl commands as cronjobs in the Kubernetes cluster results in a connection refused error

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, kubectl

When running a `kubectl` command using the `bitnami/kubectl` image from inside a kubernetes (EKS based) cluster I am expecting the command to pick up the `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` and `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT` environment variables and connect to the local cluster to run commands. Specifically I am using this to run some housekeeping [`kubernetes cronjobs`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) on the cluster but the container just errors out (and ends up in a crashBackoff loop).

The error message from the container logs is as follows:

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you
> specify the right host or port?

The `localhost:8080` is particularly odd since this has never been in use and is not configured anywhere that I am aware of - switching to a simple shell command allows the job to run successfully but kubectl refuses to work. Running `env` confirms that the `KUBE` variables are indeed being injected and set correctly. The only recent change was moving these jobs to be managed by the [terraform kubernetes cronjob resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/cron_job) rather than directly via a YAML file. Each cronjob is associated with a service account with appropriate permissions and that is still correctly configured in the cronjob.

For reference, here is a slightly redacted version of the cronjob:

```
resource "kubernetes_cron_job" "test_cronjob" {
  provider = kubernetes.region

  metadata {
    name = "test-cronjob"
    namespace = "default"
  }
  spec {
    concurrency_policy = "Allow"
    failed_jobs_history_limit = 5
    schedule = "*/5 * * * *"
    job_template {
      metadata {}
      spec {
        backoff_limit = 2
        parallelism = 1
        completions = 1
        template {
          metadata {}
          spec {
            container {
              name    = "kubectl"
              image   = "bitnami/kubectl"
              command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", <<-EOT
                                            env && echo "test";    
                                            EOT
                                            ]            
                        }
            restart_policy = "OnFailure"
            service_account_name = "sa-test"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message here is less than helpful, it implies that the issue lies with a misconfigured host and port for the cluster, but the root problem is actually a lack of credentials, despite the configured service account.

To explain, the pod spec which is part of the job contains the [automount_service_account_token](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/pod#automount_service_account_token) setting which defaults to false with Terraform. I suspect when previously managing these with `YAML` files this was being set to `true` by default.

The reason for the cryptic error is that in the absence of valid credentials, `kubectl` seems to fall back to trying the "insecure option" which, as [mentioned in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/controlling-access/#api-server-ports-and-ips), defaults to localhost and port 8080. It is reporting the error after trying that insecure option as a last resort rather than calling out a lack of credentials or giving a more helpful unauthorised error instead. After some digging it seems that this is actually an issue with the underlying `client-go` library, and it has surfaced in other ways see [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/918).

To fix this, simply set the `automount_service_account_token` back to true like so:

```
resource "kubernetes_cron_job" "test_cronjob" {
  provider = kubernetes.region

  metadata {
    name = "test-cronjob"
    namespace = "default"
  }
  spec {
    concurrency_policy = "Allow"
    failed_jobs_history_limit = 5
    schedule = "*/5 * * * *"
    job_template {
      metadata {}
      spec {
        backoff_limit = 2
        parallelism = 1
        completions = 1
        template {
          metadata {}
          spec {
            automount_service_account_token = true
            container {
              name    = "kubectl"
              image   = "bitnami/kubectl"
              command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", <<-EOT
                                            env && echo "test";    
                                            EOT
                                            ]            
                        }
            restart_policy = "OnFailure"
            service_account_name = "sa-test"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```